# Google Advanced Search

Tags: search

Is it possible to use site: and allintitle: in a google search at the same time? I want to find results with various search terms in the Google returned page title but restricted to a specific site. I know how to do either one but not both together and can't find anything at all looking online? All help shows you is how to do each separately.

Comment: Your question seems [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for Stack Overflow. It might be better suited for our sister site, http://webapps.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

No - the `allintitle` operator can **not** be used with other operators.
You can use multiple `intitle` operators instead.

For more on google searching:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_hacking

Answer (score 0):

although allintitle:, allinurl, allintext:, & allinanchor: are exclusive, you can use multiple intitle: & site: filters in the same query to achieve almost the same result as combining them with other filters, e.g.,

- intitle:(dog house) (site:cnn.com | site:*.gov)
- intitle:((cat | dog*) AROUND() people) (site:cnn.com | site:*.gov)